# How to get ethtool settings?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ioctl

Please, help me get ethtool settings (speed, duplex, autoneg).

If I use ETHTOOL_GSET, I get ethtool settings. But in ethtool.h written to use ETHTOOL_GLINKSETTINGS instead of ETHTOOL_GSET. I don't know how to use ETHTOOL_GLINKSETTINGS.

**ETHTOOL_GSET**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/ethtool.h>
#include <linux/sockios.h>

int main()
{
    int s; // socket
    int r; // result

    struct ifreq ifReq;
    strncpy(ifReq.ifr_name, "enp3s0", sizeof(ifReq.ifr_name));

    struct ethtool_cmd ethtoolCmd;
    ethtoolCmd.cmd = ETHTOOL_GSET;
    ifReq.ifr_data = &ethtoolCmd;

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (s != -1)
    {
        r = ioctl(s, SIOCETHTOOL, &ifReq);
        if (s != -1)
        {
            printf("%s | ethtool_cmd.speed = %i \n", ifReq.ifr_name, ethtoolCmd.speed);
            printf("%s | ethtool_cmd.duplex = %i \n", ifReq.ifr_name, ethtoolCmd.duplex);
            printf("%s | ethtool_cmd.autoneg = %i \n", ifReq.ifr_name, ethtoolCmd.autoneg);
        }
        else
            printf("Error #r");

        close(s);
    }
    else
        printf("Error #s");

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
enp3s0 | ethtool_cmd.speed = 1000 
enp3s0 | ethtool_cmd.duplex = 1
enp3s0 | ethtool_cmd.autoneg = 1
```

**ETHTOOL_GLINKSETTINGS**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/ethtool.h>
#include <linux/sockios.h>

int main()
{
    int s; // socket
    int r; // result

    struct ifreq ifReq;
    strncpy(ifReq.ifr_name, "enp3s0", sizeof(ifReq.ifr_name));

    struct ethtool_link_settings ethtoolLinkSettings;
    ethtoolLinkSettings.cmd = ETHTOOL_GLINKSETTINGS;
    ifReq.ifr_data = &ethtoolLinkSettings;

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (s != -1)
    {
        r = ioctl(s, SIOCETHTOOL, &ifReq);
        if (s != -1)
        {
            printf("%s | ethtool_link_settings.speed = %i \n", ifReq.ifr_name, ethtoolLinkSettings.speed);
            printf("%s | ethtool_link_settings.duplex = %i \n", ifReq.ifr_name, ethtoolLinkSettings.duplex);
            printf("%s | ethtool_link_settings.autoneg = %i \n", ifReq.ifr_name, ethtoolLinkSettings.autoneg);
        }
        else
            printf("Error #r");

        close(s);
    }
    else
        printf("Error #s");

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
enp3s0 | ethtool_link_settings.speed = 0 
enp3s0 | ethtool_link_settings.duplex = 45
enp3s0 | ethtool_link_settings.autoneg = 0
```

Why ETHTOOL_GLINKSETTINGS return incorrect values? What is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Definitely this code is a problem

```
r = ioctl(s, SIOCETHTOOL, &ifReq);
    if (s != -1)
```

how ever fixing this doesn't resolve the issue and the interface properties cannot be queried using ETHTOOL_GLINKSETTINGS. A peek into the header file shows this.

```
from /usr/include/linux/ethtool.h 

1532 /**                                                                             
1533  * struct ethtool_link_settings - link control and status                       
1534  *                                                                              
1535  * IMPORTANT, Backward compatibility notice: When implementing new              
1536  *  user-space tools, please first try %ETHTOOL_GLINKSETTINGS, and              
1537  *  if it succeeds use %ETHTOOL_SLINKSETTINGS to change link                    
1538  *  settings; do not use %ETHTOOL_SSET if %ETHTOOL_GLINKSETTINGS                
1539  *  succeeded: stick to %ETHTOOL_GLINKSETTINGS/%SLINKSETTINGS in                
1540  *  that case.  Conversely, if %ETHTOOL_GLINKSETTINGS fails, use                
1541  *  %ETHTOOL_GSET to query and %ETHTOOL_SSET to change link                     
1542  *  settings; do not use %ETHTOOL_SLINKSETTINGS if                              
1543  *  %ETHTOOL_GLINKSETTINGS failed: stick to                                     
1544  *  %ETHTOOL_GSET/%ETHTOOL_SSET in that case.
```

I do see the same behavior as reported and observe the correct values being reported using `ETHTOOL_GSET`

with `ETHTOOL_GSET`

```
~/working/exp$./ethtool-exp ens33
ens33 | ethtool_cmd.speed = 1000 
ens33 | ethtool_cmd.duplex = 1 
ens33 | ethtool_cmd.advertising= 239 
ens33 | ethtool_cmd.autoneg = 1 
ens33 | ethtool_cmd.port= 0 
ens33 | ethtool_cmd.phy_address= 0 
ens33 | ethtool_cmd.transceiver= 0 
ens33 | ethtool_cmd.maxrxpkt= 0 
ens33 | ethtool_cmd.maxtxpkt= 0
```

with `ETHTOOL_GLINKSETTINGS`

```
~/working/exp$./ethtool-glink ens33
ens33 | ethtool_link_settings.speed = 0 
ens33 | ethtool_link_settings.duplex = 0 
ens33 | ethtool_link_settings.autoneg = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in the function `do_ioctl_glinksettings()` in [ethtool.c](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/network/ethtool/ethtool/+/refs/tags/v6.0/ethtool.c), you should reserve some space behind your `ethtoolLinkSettings` buffer for the variable sized members `map_supported`, `map_advertising`, and `map_lp_advertising` (only indirectly accessible via `link_mode_masks`).

As a result of the first call of `ioctl()` you will get the real size of these members in `link_mode_masks_nwords` with a negative sign. Then set the `link_mode_masks_nwords` to this real size (non-negative) and call `ioctl()` again. Then you will get real data.

eg. (not tested)

```
int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if (fd > 0)
{
  struct ifreq ifr;
  memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
  strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, "enp3s0");

  char buffer[sizeof(struct ethtool_link_settings) + sizeof(__u32) * 3 * 128];
  struct ethtool_link_settings* ethtoolLinkSettings = (struct ethtool_link_settings*)buffer;
  memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
  ethtoolLinkSettings->cmd = ETHTOOL_GLINKSETTINGS;
  ifr.ifr_data = (caddr_t)ethtoolLinkSettings;

  if (ioctl(fd, SIOCETHTOOL, &ifr) != -1)
  {
    if (ethtoolLinkSettings->link_mode_masks_nwords < 0)
    {
      ethtoolLinkSettings->cmd = ETHTOOL_GLINKSETTINGS;
      ethtoolLinkSettings->link_mode_masks_nwords = -ethtoolLinkSettings->link_mode_masks_nwords;

      if (ioctl(fd, SIOCETHTOOL, &ifr) != -1)
      {
        printf("%s | ethtool_link_settings.speed = %i \n", ifReq.ifr_name, ethtoolLinkSettings.speed);
        printf("%s | ethtool_link_settings.duplex = %i \n", ifReq.ifr_name, ethtoolLinkSettings.duplex);
        printf("%s | ethtool_link_settings.autoneg = %i \n", ifReq.ifr_name, ethtoolLinkSettings.autoneg);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This approach fixes "error: flexible array member ‘ethtool_link_settings::link_mode_masks’ not at end of" build error for C++ and GCC 12 if you take the `struct ecmd` from `ethtool.c` directly,

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the following typo:

```
r = ioctl(s, SIOCETHTOOL, &ifReq);
    if (s != -1)
```

You meant to check the value of `r`, but you mistakenly check `s` instead.
If you correct that mistake, I believe you will get an error (EOPNOTSUPP, Operation not supported).

Comment: Yes, you are right. When I corrected the typo, then I got the error message "Error #r". So how do I get information about ethtool?

Comment: @user7461659, wording from `/usr/include/linux/ethtool.h` may help: `IMPORTANT, When implementing new user-space tools, please first try ETHTOOL_GLINKSETTINGS, and if it fails, use ETHTOOL_GSET to query...`

Answer (score 0):

As you see for setting Link Speed we are using Ethtool_SSET.
For setting Ethtool speed, we need check the other parameter of ethetool_cmd structure such as
Transcribed
Maxtxpkt
Maxrxpkt

All the above parameter of Ethtool_cmd should not be non-zero.

I was facing issue in setting the speed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Make sure to always include code on your answer! [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).